# Compare two ZonedDateTime with ignoring the Zone

Tags: java, java-stream, zoneddatetime

Compare two `ZonedDateTime` with ignoring the Zone:

Example:

`2022-08-17 03:30:00+02` compare `2022-08-17 03:30:00+01` must give `true`

I Have a stream that must compare each object with others using this Date:

```
Set<Tele> jPointsSet = jPoints.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> 
                                new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Tele::getDateM))));
```

the `getDateM` is `ZonedDateTime` so I would like when use `Comparator.comparing(Tele::getDateM))` ignore the Zone

Comment: If you just want to ignore the zone part of your `ZonedDateTime`, wouldn't just using `toLocalDateTime()` on both of them and comparing the `LocalDateTime` objects be a solution?

Comment: You opt for the similar time in the day: the height of sun or moon being the same. That is simply getting the `LocalDateTime`. Others might want the same time for a video conference, that would be converting to the UTC zone. And the time strings you showed are of OffsetDateTime, a help class. A ZonedDateTime indicates the Locale which specifies the Day Savings Time specifying an offset which may differ per summer/winter. And be different for the same lattitude (Africa/Europe).

Answer (score 1):

As *@OH GOD SPIDERS* said in the comments, you can extract `LocalDateTime` from a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Comparator.comparing(tele -> tele.getDateM().toLocalDateTime())
```

But be aware that if two `LocalDateTime` instances are equal, it doesn't necessarily mean that they're describing the same point in time. In order to establish comparison based on a specific point in the global timeline, you need to use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#method-summary).

```
Comparator.comparing(tele -> tele.getDateM().toInstant())
```

**Sidenote:** while dealing with a `TreeSet`, it's more handy to use [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) interface as an abstract type. It gives you access to methods like `pollFirst()`, `pollLast()`, `lower()`, `higher()`, etc. which are not declared in the `Set` interface.